# How to attach a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a Pandas dataframe in Python. Whenever I want to calculate something, I need to type the entire dataframe name and the column name like `dataframe_name.column_name`. Previously I worked on R, where we can attach the dataframe using `attach(dataframe_name)`. Is there anything like that we can do in Python Pandas library?

Comment: Whenever possible, try to use `dataframe['COLUMN']`, not `dataframe.COLUMN` as the latter can have side effects

Answer (score 0):

Just write `dataframe_name['new_column_name']=...` and new column will be added.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there anything like that we can do in Python Pandas library?*

You might get similar effect as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6],"c":[7,8,9]})
globals().update(df.to_dict(orient="series"))
c[2] = 12
print(df)
```

output

```
   a  b   c
0  1  4   7
1  2  5   8
2  3  6  12
```

but beware that is rather unexpected way of working with `pandas.DataFrame` and might cause weird behavior as this might overshadow built-ins.